# Can we collect the stars we get on chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat

It's always fun to be collecting stuff (rep, badges etc) so it would be fun to see somewhere how many stars you've gotten on chat. I asked Marc on The Tavern and he wasn't against it but it's just a matter of finding the time.

The metric would have no meaning, just a number so if it would be abused, then it would have no effect on the system.

What do you guys think?

Comment: My support for this endeavor relies solely on whether we get an awesome bonus for collecting 120 stars.

Comment: @Grace It changes the chat alert sound to Mario saying "woo-hoo!"

Comment: @Michael: that, and you have to start all over again and collect 120 *green* stars. How's that for a challenge?

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting but there would be other features I would want before this one.

Also, this stat would be an orphan stat in your profile.   I would prefer to see a silver "talkative" badge that would be something like 20 stared comments in chat.

Comment: I don't think that's really on par with the other silver badges; getting 20 starred messages is...less than difficult

Comment: @Michael, well you only have to get one for the bronze badge.  So I was thinking 20 would be more on the silver level, but I would be fine with 50 or 100 if that was more reasonable.

Comment: This would obviously be a low priority item.

Comment: @jzd, there's already [Outspoken](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/138/outspoken)

Comment: @Benjol, Outspoken did not exist when I answered this question.  It is relatively new.

Comment: @jzd, oh, ok. I knew it was new, didn't think it was that new.

Comment: @Benjol, from the feature change question:  "2011-02-22: Outspoken badge introduced."